# Where is the "Project Paint" and "Layer" option in Blender 2.77a?

Tags: texture-painting, versions

I am now following a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/sZDMFkj8GqA?t=7m54s) that teaches texture painting in Blender 2.61. But I cannot find the `Project Paint` and the `Layer` option in my version of Blender (2.77a). Where are they in Blender 2.7x?

The left-hand side is a shot from the YouTube video. The right-hand side is the menu in my blender 2.77a.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the video uses 2.61 not 2.7x. I edited your question to reflect this.

The project paint panel resides in the options tab, and the uv layer select is in the slots panel of the slots tab.

[image]

---

### Blender User Interface Terms

[image: Panel]

[image: Tab]

[image: Context]

[image: Window]

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot of the menu. There is no `Project Paint` =[.

Comment: The project paint panel can be found in the [Options tab](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/tabs_panels.html).

Comment: @CasperLIWaiKin Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Please see my updated answer.